# Layered navigation doesn't appear in mobile view (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, mobile

I created a layered navigation using an attribute to filter colors. This color filter is the only filter I am using and **works in desktop view well**. But in mobile view the filter doesn't show up. I also tried it in Luma Theme but it doesn't show up there too. Do I need to activate layered navigation for mobile somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Magento Blank theme (and I assume Luma as well) shows the layered navigation in the mobile layout. I believe the exception is if you're using the `2column-right` layout. Anything in the right column is hidden for mobile layouts.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the link to open the filters in mobile view. It works in Luma and in Magento Blank well. But not in my Theme, javascript to click open seems to not work.

Answer (score 0):

5 years later, but I hope it serves someone.
Try this in your theme's extend file:

```
// Mobile

.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'max') and (@break = @screen__m)
{

.block-title 
    {
            overflow: visible;
    }
}
```